# Fetch Core Data entity with a filtered set of child elements based on a property

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I'm developing my first application with CoreData and I'm struggling with a common problem I think.

Let's say I have an entity Playlist which has a *many to many* relationship with another entity Song and also Video. So my Playlist object looks like this

```
class Playlist : NSManagedObject {
    var songs: NSSet
    var videos: NSSet
}
```

Song and Video entities both have a Boolean field "removed" that I use to track which song or video has been removed from the playlist. I later call my remote API to remove it on server's side but this is for offline purpose.

What I want is to retrieve from CoreData a Playlist object with its list of songs and videos that are not removed (so those with removed = false).

One solution I see would be to get all the elements by simply fetching on the Entity Playlist and then filter out manually but I'd like to know if I can do this more elegantly using Core Data.

Comment: You could just use an `NSPredicate` to filter the `songs` and `videos` properties of the playlist.  Alternatively, you could use an NSFetchRequest to get the Song and Videos entities with a predicate that their `playlist` property matches your playlist and the `removed` property is `false`.  Either way, you will need to do Songs and Videos separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Core Data. The way this works is a follows:

First fetch the playlists. They have a to-many relationship with songs no matter if they are deleted of not. The `removed` property is not in the `Playlist` entity, so it does not matter when fetching playlists.

Then get the *filtered* attribute set by applying a predicate:

```
let validSongs = aPlaylist.songs.filteredSetUsingPredicate(
   NSPredicate(format: "removed = false")
)
```

In other words, you do not have to worry about which songs exactly Core Data is retrieving with your playlist. There are a lot of optimizations under the hood, so most likely Core Data will be using a mechanism called "faulting" to just retrieve the data it needs. There is noting else for you to do!

IMO, this is also the most "elegant" solution. To make it even more concise, you can add a method to your `Playlist` entity that retrieves the valid songs.

```
func validSongs() -> NSSet {
   if !self.songs.count {  return NSSet()  }
   return self.songs.filteredSetUsingPredicate(
      NSPredicate(format: "removed = false")
   ) 
}
```

And then access the valid songs with

```
aPlaylist.validSongs
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the explication, it's clear to me now.